# how to choose a dual power supply for rail to rail amplifier?

Tags: operational-amplifier, dc-dc-converter, buck-boost, negative-voltage

I need +15VDC and -15VDC dual supply for rail to rail supply of op-amp.
I have found buck-boost inverters used for this task.
I have a doubt whether the inductor in the buck-boost inverter circuit can affect or add noise to the amplifier circuit? 
I have found several circuits as follows

```
1. charge pump inverter 

2. voltage inverter 

3. buck-boost inverter 

4. positive and negative switching power supply
```

which one is most suitable for noise sensitive application?

examples
[module 1](https://www.ebay.com/itm/173594156796)
[module 2](https://www.seeedstudio.com/PNMini-2A-Mini-Power-module-for-DIY-Electronic-Projects-p-1914.html)
[module 3](https://www.ebay.com/itm/TPS5430-Positive-Negative-Dual-Power-Supply-Module-with-Switching-12V-output/172909586228?hash=item284236e734:g:xXQAAOSwIxVcw9YP)

Comment: The devil is in the detailed design and not in generalities.

Comment: All the supplies you list *will* add noise; the issue is what can your particular circuit accept.

Comment: @Peter Smith my application is a thermocouple amplifier

Comment: what about positive & negative linear voltage regulator ?

Comment: Stop being "general". Peter Smith asked what your particular circuit can accept. Stating that your application is a thermocouple amplifier is a generalism - as I said, the devil is in the detail.

Comment: I have only 5V, 12V, and 24V DC power, no AC power ( no transformer involvement)

Comment: @ Andy aka, I do not understand what you mean by   "what your particular circuit can accept."

Comment: What is meant is: there is no supply which delivers power with **ZERO** noise. Some supplies generate more noise and ripple than others. What is **most important** is to find out what your circuit needs. "The lowest noise" is not an answer. A proper answer is 1uV or 1 mV or 100 mV. You might be using a circuit which has an opamp with a very high PSRR, then you might be able to allow more noise and ripple on the supply. A thermocouple is a low-frequency measurement (nearly DC) so any noise in the amplified signal can be filtered out.

Comment: I once designed an Op Amp low power supply with a transformer, PWM and   was so RF quiet, that it didn't need a ground plane or a shield and regulated hi-kV DC ramp generators for a Lexmark Laser printer. Of course, it used gain-modulated sinewaves and not a SMPS.

Answer (score 2):

I like the cheapest solution US $2.88

But provide room to add a tin-plated brass or steel foil Faraday shield with an RC filter to desireable breakpoint near 10 Hz. There may be noise from this to the source may need shielding, isolation and filtering. **How much? depends on your specs.**

Also, when the **output hits the rail, there is no PSRR.**  *zero, 0dB nada, none*

### Module 1 specs at bottom of your link says 20 mA minimum load for best results.

```
    3W DC-DC Boost Converter 3.3V-12V to ± 15V Output Step up Power Supply Module.   
　
 Description:◦  Features:
```

±15V step-up module, 3W positive and negative output boost module, low 3.3VDC input, non-isolated DC-DC 
Power modules, Can replace LM78XX / 79XX three-terminal regulator chip.           Wide voltage input: 3.3-13VDC     Boost Dual output: ±15V     Efficiency: 82%     Size: 23.5 * 14 * 6.3mm

```
Support single in-line or horizontal installation DIP
```

Conversion efficiency: 5V input, full 3W output, 82%

```
        -  Ripple noise: **5V input, full 3W output, 60 ~ 120mV**.  
             - Port definition:                   VIN: 3.3V to 13V DC input     GND: Input Output Common GND     +Vo: Output Positive.         -Vo: Output negative.       NC: Vacant port, no electrical connection     En: Module enables:     VEN < 0.8V, the module does not work;     1.4V < VEN < VIN or EN vacant when the module normal output.
   NOTE: VEN < 0.8V, the circuit configuration restrictions, +Vo Vin voltage output at this time still, but -Vo no voltage output.
```

Precautions

1. The module does not support output short circuit protection board.
2. The output current is greater than 20mA can get a better product overall performance.
3. When -Vo overloaded, + Vo load is too light, it is recommended to increase the dummy load resistor between ground terminal and + Vo terminal.

Comment: I will be using AD8495

Comment: Add LPF to  supply rails and  20mA dummy  loads